# Error: chrome_driver_path = YOUR_PATH_TO_THE_CHROME_DRIVER NameError: name 'YOUR_PATH_TO_THE_CHROME_DRIVER' is not defined

Tags: python, list

chrome_driver_path = YOUR_PATH_TO_THE_CHROME_DRIVER
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)

Comment: **YOUR_PATH_TO_THE_CHROME_DRIVER** is just a variable in python. You should define like  **chrome_driver_path = r"C:\chromedriver.exe"**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.